# Ударение в японском имени Норико

Tags: орфоэпия, ономастика, переводы, имена

Норикó, как в японском, или Нóрика, как в аудиопереводчике? Где поставить ударение? И в конце произносить, как у японцев — "o" или как в аудиопереводчике — "а"?